# ADO execute againt SQL Server does not report on referential integrity constraints

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, ado

Evidence is that when using ADO to delete a record in SQL Server, it does not report back on referential integrity constraints.

- Master table : `tblMasterChecklist`
- Child table : `tblMasterTopic` (references `tblmasterchecklist.checklistid`)

Code:

```
Dim ado As New adodb.Connection
Dim sConnectionString As String

ON error goto eh

sConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hillhead-100;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXXX;UID=XXXXXXXXXXXXX;PWD=XXXXXXXXXXXX;"
ado.Open (sConnectionString)
ado.execute "DELETE FROM tblMasterChecklist  WHERE ChecklistID = 'DE'"
```

I get this error:

> Error =  3001, Application Error  3001, Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

This same command will work OK as long as there are no child records present

This would appear to be a limitation of the driver.

Can anyone advise on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, do not use `SQLOLEDB`. That driver is part of MDAC, which is conveniently installed on all Windows machines since Windows XP SP2, but also dates back to Windows XP SP2, and is very outdated. It's deprecated, and doesn't implement many basic features, such as support for "modern" data types such as `DateTime2`.

Instead, use `MSOLEDBSQL`, the only OLEDB provider that's currently supported for SQL server.

You should be able to download the latest version [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server).

Alternatively, use an ODBC driver, as ADO supports both ODBC and OLEDB.

Comment: Thanks Erik A for the clarification. Your answer is a succinct summary of exactly what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

sConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxxxx;UID=xxxxxxxxxxx;PWD=xxxxxxxxxxxx;"

Error trapped:
04-Jun-2020 22:18:57; 4.19; xxxx; Error; 4.19; Problem deleting MasterChecklist info, clsMasterChecklist, mbDelete, Error = -2147217873, Application Error -2147217873, The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_tblMasterTopic_tblMasterChecklist". The conflict occurred in database "xxxxxxxxxxxx", table "dbo.tblMasterTopic", column 'checklistid'.